# Combining 2 rows

Tags: t-sql

I have a result set that looks like this. I would like to sum the paid amount and combine the DTV TOW and FlatBED into 1 row. Is there any way I can accomplish?

```
CaseServiceID   PurchaseOrderID PaidAmount  DTV TOW FLATBED
227                 15000227    19.20           1   0
227                 15000227    45.00           0   1
```

note: `DTV TOW` and `FLATBED` columns are from a pivoted table

*Edit*

Pivot looks like this:

```
select
*
from
(
    select
    cla.CaseServiceID
    ,cla.ServiceTypeProgKey
    ,cla.ClaimAmount
    ,cla.PaidAmount
    ,cla.ClaimQuantity
    from
    Claim cla
) as srcServiceType
pivot
(
    max(ServiceTypeProgKey) for ServiceTypeProgKey in ([FLATBED],[DTV TOW]
) as pvtServiceType
```

Comment: Can you show your pivot query?

Comment: @DanAndrews, it's been updated. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming PaidAmount and ClaimQuantity are <strike>bit</strike> TinyInt used as a boolean) else change MAX to SUM:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT cla.CaseServiceID,
        cla.ServiceTypeProgKey,
        SUM(cla.ClaimAmount) ClaimAmount,
        MAX(cla.PaidAmount) PaidAmount,
        MAX(cla.ClaimQuantity) ClaimQuantity
    FROM Claim cla
    GROUP BY cla.CaseServiceID,
        cla.ServiceTypeProgKey
    ) AS srcServiceType
pivot(max(ServiceTypeProgKey) FOR ServiceTypeProgKey IN (
            [FLATBED],
            [DTV TOW]
            ) AS pvtServiceType)
```

Comment: FYI, [you can't aggregate `bit` data directly](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/20649)

Comment: @AndriyM Thanks for the information, I always use TinyInts instead of bit anyway (for indexing purposes) therefore I miss issues when other people use them.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
SELECT CaseServiceID, 
       PurchaseOrderID, 
       SUM(PaidAmount) PaidAmount,
       SUM([DTV TOW]) [DTV TOW],
       SUM(FLATBED) FLATBED
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CaseServiceID, PurchaseOrderID
```

Answer (score -1):

What the query ultimately looked like. I hope this helps someone. Thanks

```
select
,sum(isnull([FLATBED], 0)) AS [FLATBED]
,sum(isnull([DTV TOW], 0)) AS [DTV TOW]
from
(
    select
    cla.ServiceTypeProgKey,
    ,sum(cla.PaidAmount) as 'PaidAmount'
    ,sum(cla.ClaimQuantity) as 'ClaimQuantity'
    ,sum(cla.PaidQuantity) as 'PaidQuantity'
    from
    Claim cla
    inner join CaseService cse on cla.CaseServiceID = cse.CaseServiceID
    group by cse.PurchaseOrderID
) as srcServiceType
pivot
(
     count(ServiceTypeProgKey) FOR ServiceTypeProgKey IN ([FLATBED],[DTV TOW])
) as pvtServiceType
```

...and the result

```
CaseServiceID   PurchaseOrderID   PaidAmount  DTV   TOW FLATBED
227             15000227          64.20       1     1
```